# back button not working after javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a widget which is embedded in random sites. when the user clicks I call the server to update the click occured and the server returns redirect to the correct page. The problem is that the Back button of the browser no longer works.

I use location.href for the redirect.

I tried location.replace -which keeps the back button , but it goes to the page before the page in which the widget was clicked (it replaces it with the new page).

How can I do the page switch after reporting to the server and still allow the back button to work?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot go back to a page that auto-redirects.  That's just a broken back button and a frustrated user.

```
User goes to page A.
User clicks on link to page B.
Page B automatically redirects to page C with window.location.
User hits back button and momentarily goes back to page B.
Page B automatically redirects to page C with window.location.
User hits back button and momentarily goes back to page B.
Page B automatically redirects to page C with window.location.
User is sad.
```

Obviously this doesn't work.  It has to work like this instead:

```
User goes to page A.
User clicks on link to page B.
Page B automatically redirects to page C with window.location.replace().
User hits back button and goes back to page A.
User is happy.
```

You must auto-redirect with window.location.replace() if you want the back button to work.

Comment: Nice concept.
Its not ideal for me because I need to implement page B and send all sort of info there for the server side report. Since its a widget which is not on my own site its a problem. But it may be a workaround I'll use if no better alternative comes up.

Comment: Sounds odd to me.  You're saying you have to put lots of info in Page B, but the user is automatically redirected away from page B.  I guess I don't understand why the user needs to see page B?

Comment: old post, I know, but on my case, page B has some important notice that the user must read but due to a 15 seconds time out, got redirected, and user wants to go back and read it for another 15 seconds.

Comment: @Jacobski - Please post your own question with your specific details and question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, that is not a question. I am just supporting the OP about his question and commenting about your answer saying "User is sad" that what if the user really intends to go back just so he could finish reading what was on that page before he got redirected. I hope you understand my point of view, fellow developer.