# Redirect based on browser language in Gatsby

Tags: redirect, routes, gatsby

I am building a site based on Gatsby. The english content is accessible with "/" and the german content with "/de". This is handled by the following plugin: https://github.com/angeloocana/gatsby-plugin-i18n.

Now I would like to detect the browser language and redirect the user to either "/" or "/de". What I understood so far is that it's not easy to get this behaviour with Gatsby, as Gatsby renders and builds the routing on the server-side.

What's the best way to detect the language of a user and redirect to either "/" or "/de"

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this

UPDATE: `{replace: true}` was added to support browsers like Firefox. Read the comments below this answer for a better context on when to use `{replace: true}`. Thanks to  Frederik Baetens for the heads up.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { navigate } from "gatsby";

const getRedirectLanguage = () => {
  if (typeof navigator === `undefined`) {
    return "en";
  }

  const lang = navigator && navigator.language && navigator.language.split("-")[0];
  if (!lang) return "en";

  switch (lang) {
    case "ja":
      return "ja";
    default:
      return "en";
  }
};

const IndexPage = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const urlLang = getRedirectLanguage();

    navigate(`/${urlLang}/`, {replace: true});
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Credits to https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/21548

Comment: This breaks the back button in firefox though, do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Ohh I didn't test it on Firefox. I don't have but feel free to provide a solution for it 

Comment: I submitted an edit for approval to fix it, based on: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#replace-history-during-programmatic-navigation

Comment: Yes, [some more on why to do automatic redirects with replace (generic for JS, not just gatsby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805404/back-button-not-working-after-javascript-redirect)

Why the back button [wasn't broken in chrome](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/12/google-chrome-wants-to-stop-back-button-hijacking/)
So by not using replace, we were essentially accidentally becoming one of these malicious sites. The problem was that without a replace, upon pressing the back button, a user would go back to the original page, which immediately redirects them again.

Comment: For future readers wanting to use gatsby navigate for other things than an automatic redirect, for example navigating upon clicking a button, or other redirects based on user actions, you wouldn't use the replace. It's only for automatic redirects that you generally want to use replace.

Comment: I use navigator in my code and when in local it works fine, but once built and deployed to production, it errors out and complaining `no navigator object`